# Secure Property Placeholder Module not populating - MuleSoft Anypoint Studio

Tags: plugins, mule, esb, anypoint-studio

I have installed the Anypoint Enterprise Security - http://anypoint-enterprise-security-update-site.s3.amazonaws.com/1.7.1 and been using the ability to Encrypt and Decrypt passwords. This was working fine for a while.

[image]

Today, my 'Secure Property Placeholder' is not working.

If I add it manually in XML I see the following in my 'Global Elemetns'

[image]

If I try to add a new 'Secure Property Placeholder' it does not give me that option:

[image]

But I have the package installed in my Anypoint.

I'm not sure what I did or what happened. I've tried:
1. Uninstalling the 'Secure Property Placeholder Module' and Reinstalling
2. Uninstall the entire Enterprise Package and Reinstalling

But Nothing is working.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Anypoint studio?

Answer (score 1):

A similar problem occured to me with another mule connector. In my case, I had a lower version Mule Server RunTime and the connector was of a higher version. In your case I see that you have both Mule ESB server 3.8.5 and Mule ESB server 3.9.0 EE. Your Enterprise Security is of version 3.9.0. Now when you add the security component to your project, make sure that you have it running on the Mule ESB server 3.9.0 and not on the 3.8.5 version. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing from anypoint exchange rather than Help/Install New Software, I was having a similar problem which seems to be resolved now.